# Bring the data from two tables into one table with where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two files I have bulk imported into two tables which have overlapping dates. Now I want to move the data from both tables into a new table but remove the overlapping dates. This is my code to do that:

```
-- Pull across data from P1-10 and exclude out of scope dates
SELECT      *
INTO        I_Inventory
FROM        I_Inventory_P10_Temp
WHERE       [date] >= '01/01/2016' and [date] <= '10/31/16'

-- Pull across data from P11-12 and exclude out of scope dates
SELECT      *
INTO        I_Inventory
FROM        I_Inventory_P12_Temp
WHERE       [date] >= '11/01/2016' and [date] <= '12/31/16'
```

However this doesn't work because it says the table already exists after the first select into. Can someone please let me know how to approach this? I'm quite new to SQL.

Comment: Check out UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `UNION ALL` to combine the results and then insert into table

```
SELECT      *
INTO        I_Inventory
FROM        I_Inventory_P10_Temp
WHERE       [date] >= '01/01/2016' and [date] <= '10/31/16'
Union All
-- Pull across data from P11-12 and exclude out of scope dates
SELECT      *
FROM        I_Inventory_P12_Temp
WHERE       [date] >= '11/01/2016' and [date] <= '12/31/16'
```

Comment: Two different tables, so the two first queries wont work.

Comment: @jarlh - Thanks didnt see that ;)